# SwiftUI iOS 14 Widget CountDown

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

I have a iOS 14 widget with a Countdown

```
Text(foo, style: .timer)
```

How can I change text color to red when the time is less than 1 minute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can create a countdown for `1 minute` with the text color changing to red when it's `10 seconds` left. When the time is over the countdown starts again.

1. Create an Entry where `displayDate` is the total time (here 1 minute):

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let displayDate: Date
    var isDateClose = false
}
```

2. In your Provider create two Entries - one for the *standard* color and one for the *isClose* color (here *red*):

```
struct SimpleProvider: TimelineProvider {
    ...

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> Void) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let firstDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 50, to: currentDate)!
        let secondDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 60, to: currentDate)!

        let entries = [
            SimpleEntry(date: currentDate, displayDate: secondDate),
            SimpleEntry(date: firstDate, displayDate: secondDate, isDateClose: true),
        ]

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

3. Use it in your view:

```
struct SimpleWidgetEntryView: View {
    var entry: SimpleProvider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.displayDate, style: .timer)
            .foregroundColor(entry.isDateClose ? .red : .primary)
    }
}
```

---

<sub>Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples#countdown-widget) with different Widget examples including the Countdown Widget.</sub>

Comment: Hi, could please describe how this code works? Because I can not see decrementing the time. Thanks

Comment: how to stop timer once timer reach at 0 ?

Comment: What about we use `ActivityConfiguration` for new lock screen widgets?