# How to use @FetchRequest data in Provider struct in iOS 14 Widget

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I'm trying to develop a `timer App` using `Core Data` and `iOS 14 Widget`.

I want to display `00:00` when the value of duration in `Core Data` is `0.0` in the widget.
So I refer to this article [SwiftUI iOS 14 Widget CountDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155800/swiftui-ios-14-widget-countdown).

In this article, I have to use data fetched from Core Data in `struct Provider: TimelineProvider`.

But When I declare a variable using `@FetchRequest` in `struct Provider: TimelineProvider` the data from Core Data never display. (`// Display_A` in the code I attached bellow)

In the case of using `@FetchRequest` in `struct TimerWidgetEntryView : View` the data display well. (`// Display_B` in the code I attached bellow)

This is a screenshot of my widget

[image]

My goal is to display `20.0` in both `Display_A` and `Display_B` in my code.

How could I do that?

---

Here is the code:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    
    init(context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = context
    }
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: TimerEntity.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(
                                                                    key:"createdDate",ascending:true)],animation:.spring()) var timerEntity:FetchedResults<TimerEntity>
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        return SimpleEntry(date: Date(), duration: timerEntity.first?.duration ?? 0.0)
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), duration: timerEntity.first?.duration ?? 0.0)
        return completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, duration: timerEntity.first?.duration ?? 0.0)
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let duration: Double
}

struct TimerWidgetEntryView : View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: TimerEntity.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(
                                                                    key:"createdDate",ascending:true)],animation:.spring()) var timerEntity:FetchedResults<TimerEntity>
        
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        return (
            VStack{
                Text(String(entry.duration)) // Display_A
                Text(String(timerEntity.first?.duration ?? 0.0)) // Display_B
            }
        )
    }
}

@main
struct TimerWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "TimerWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider(context: PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)) { entry in
            TimerWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Comment: `@FetchRequest` cannot be used in Widgets. See [Fetch data from CoreData for iOS 14 widget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63936425/8697793)

Comment: @ pawello2222, Thank you for your information !!