# iOS16 bug in SwiftUI.Text(_: Date, style: Text.DateStyle)

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios16

I made some widget that used to as a digital clock formatted HH:mm:ss

below is code, or ref: [SwiftUI iOS 14 Widget CountDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155800/swiftui-ios-14-widget-countdown)

```swift
    let todayMidnight: Date // this property means today's midnight date&time Ex) 2022-08-30 0:0:0, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    Text(todayMidnight, style: .timer)
```

before iOS16 beta, it works well but, not now

I know other way that insert Entry per second to timeline
but first time, I thk it doing well, but after some time, stopped

App [WidgetSmith](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/widgetsmith/id1523682319) have problem same like me

is someone know about this?

Comment: even ui alignment is wrong too, only style: .timer, others is going well

Comment: Please add what is not working, and what is breaking, also i think you should provide a bit more context about the extension you built

Comment: why the hell Text(...,.timer) not working in iOS 16 widget, does anybody found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in iOS 16.0.
I have submitted feedback.
The good news is that this problem has been fixed in the latest version of iOS16.1